# How to connect to Kafka brokers via proxy over tcp (don't want to use kafka rest)

Tags: apache-kafka, tcp, proxy

[Please find the screen shot, what we are trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqsby.png)

Our deployment servers can't connect to internet directly without proxy. Hence needed a way to send messages to outside organization kafka cluster. Please note that we do not want to use kafka rest.

Comment: Kafka doesn't require the "Internet", but it does require a direct network connection, so where exactly are you planning on running the proxy, if you could? If it's in your own network, there should be no significant difference in routing tables between your Java clients' network requests and the proxy's

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Kafka is very complex and doesn't support this scenario; when you first connect to the bootstrap servers; they send the actual connections the client needs to make, based on the broker properties (advertised listeners).

Comment: Well, there are projects on Github literally called `kafka-proxy` that are inspired by GCP's CloudSQL proxy

Comment: Looks interesting. I wasn’t aware of that.